Splitting field degree of a polynomial over a number field
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. Consider the polynomial $f(x) \in K[x]$,
$$f(x) = x^6 + (-1/(3\sqrt{3}) - 1/2)x^5 + ((-1/(6\sqrt{2}) + 1/6)\sqrt{3} - 1/(3\sqrt{2}) - 1/3)x^4 + ((1/(3\sqrt{2}) + 1/3)\sqrt{3} + 1/(2\sqrt{2}))x^3 + ((-1/(6\sqrt{2}) + 1/6)\sqrt{3} - 1/(3\sqrt{2}) - 1/3)x^2 + (-1/(3\sqrt{3}) - 1/2)x + 1$$
SageMath tells me the absolute degree of a splitting field of $f(x)$ is 192. I thought the splitting field is just $L=K[x]/(f(x))$ since $f(x)$ is irreducible. Then $[L:K]=6$ and $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, so $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=24$. It also tells me the extension $L/K$ is not Galois. For a splitting field the extension should be separable and we would have $[L:K] = |\text{Gal}(L/K)|$. $f(x)$ has distinct complex roots over $\mathbb{C}$.
Is it possible to compute the splitting field of $f(x)$ without a computer, and why aren't the roots just in $L$?

Irreducibility of $f$ does not imply that $K[x]/(f(x))$ is the splitting field. In fact, for a generic polynomial this extension is unlikely to be normal.

Is $-1/3\sqrt3$ meant to be $-\frac1{3\sqrt3}$ or $-\frac13\sqrt3?$

@ThomasAndrews $-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$. Sorry, that's the way Sage outputs it. I'll fix it. Okay, but I'm confused. Doesn't the construction in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field#The_construction] imply that for a single irreducible polynomial, you just get $K[x]/(f(x))$?

@Jackson: no it doesn't. That construction already starts with a single polynomial.

@QiaochuYuan Ah, okay, thanks I see now. You just get at least one root when you work over $K_{i+1}[x]/(f(x))$. You have to keep going.

Yes, that's right, and in the worst case you get exactly one root each time.

$L = K[x]/f(x)$ is not the splitting field; this is the field obtained by adjoining a single root of $f$, and the splitting field is obtained by adjoining all roots of $f$. Let's step away from your large complicated polynomial and consider a much simpler example, namely
$$g(x) = x^3 - 2$$
over $\mathbb{Q}$. The extension $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - 2) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not Galois; this has nothing to do with separability, it's because it's not normal. The splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)$ where $\omega^3 = 1$ is a primitive third root of unity, which has degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$; this matches the size of the Galois group in this case, which is $S_3$.
More explicitly, in the general construction of the splitting field, after adjoining a single root (which in this case gives $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, you are supposed to factor $g(x)$ over this extension. In this case you get
$$g(x) = (x - \sqrt[3]{2})(x^2 + \sqrt[3]{2} x + \sqrt[3]{4}).$$
This second quadratic factor remains irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, so the construction continues by adjoining a root of this quadratic. This produces the splitting field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega \sqrt[3]{2}) \cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)$.
Generally, for an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$, the extension $L = K[x]/f(x)$ is Galois iff the Galois group $G$ has order $n = \deg f$, in which case its action on the roots of $f$ is necessarily free. When $n = 3$ this happens iff the Galois group is $A_3 \cong C_3$. When $n = 4$ this happens iff the Galois group is $C_4$ or the transitive copy of $V_4$ in $S_4$.
In the "generic" case the Galois group is $S_n$ and $L$ is extremely far from being Galois. What happens in this case is that the construction of the splitting field takes as long as possible: after adjoining each root and dividing by it, the remaining polynomial remains irreducible, so one needs to adjoin roots $n - 1$ times and get extensions of degrees $n, n-1, n-2, \dots $, for a total degree of $n!$, matching the size of $S_n$.
